# WSO2 ESB How to measure the response time of call or send mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any official supported way to show the exact response time of call or send mediator from WSO2 ESB ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt **Synapse Message Context Property** and do this easily. The Synapse Message Context Property can retrieve the current time in milliseconds and you can set this value to a property at any desired point of the flow and access it whenever you need it.

You can set the property as shown below.

```
<property name="TIME" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"/>
...
<log>
 <property name="Time : " expression="get-property('TIME')"/>
</log>
...
```

Let's say you've logged the starting time and the end time as two properties named '*TIME_START*' and '*TIME_END*', you can take the time difference using a script mediator as shown in the example below.

```
<script language="js">
 var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_START");
 var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_END");
 var timeDifference = time2 - time1;
 print("Response Time :  " + timeDifference + " ms ");
 mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeDifference);
</script>
```

The following is a sample proxy service with the response time calculation bit.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SampleTimeProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="TIME_START"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="LONG"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
         <property name="TIME_END"
                   expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="LONG"/>
         <script language="js">
              var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_START");
              var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_END");
              var timeDifference = time2 - time1;
              print("--------------  " + timeDifference + " ms  -----------------");
              mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeDifference);
         </script>
         <log>
            <property name="Response Time in ms: " expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME')"/>
         </log>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SampleService"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/SampleService?wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Here we are setting the response time as another property named '*RESPONSE_TIME*'.

You can read more on this blog: http://sumedhask.blogspot.com/2013/10/a-simple-way-to-log-time-durations-in.html